# Creating a child theme: How do I find the template name of the parent directory?

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

I am trying to create a child theme for the Fitness Hub theme. I'm following this guide (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), when it comes to part 2. it makes it clear I need to add a 'Template' header in the style.css (of the child theme), however there isn't a template name in the parent theme's style.css. So it's not clear to me what this template name should be. I used 'Template: fitnesshub', but this doesn't work, the child theme does not generate. I get the following error in my themes directory (on the browser):

> The parent theme is missing. Please install the "fitnesshub" parent
> theme.

When I install the parent theme (clicking the link) the same issue occurs.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Theme handbook (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

you need to use the parent theme dir name in the 'Template' header. In your case the template name would be.

`Template: fitness-hub`

Comment: This is the correct answer.